# is there a C library for validating XML against a XML schema?

Tags: c, xml, xsd

See question. Also any links to example code or example code on how to validate an xml file against multiple schemas would be helpful.

EDT: Sorry forgot to mention that this is for LINUX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're targeting Windows platforms, you can use [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742(VS.85).aspx), but your use case has to allow COM.

EDIT: Apache has an open-source XML library called [Xerces-C++](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) that supports schema validation.  It's not C-compatible, but if you can get away with using C++, it should do what you need.

Answer (score 4):

[libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) is portable, pure C and [implements XML Schema](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlschemas.html). It is also open-source (MIT license) and has an active developer community.